# Segmentation Fault when loading image pixel by pixel using CImg

Tags: c++, image, cimg

I am trying to compute the mean of an image by loading pixel by pixel.
My image has 6 channels, height and with are 512 and depth is 1.
It is stored at the first position of an ImgList containing 2 elements.

My code is as follows:

```
int main(){
float mean = 0;
CImgList<float> img;
int c, x, y;
for(c=0; c<6; ++c)
    for(x=0; x<512; ++x)
        for(y=0; y<512; ++y){
            img.load_cimg("test_images/Simul_PolSAR.cimg", 0, 0, x, y, 0, c, x, y, 0, c);
            mean += img(0)(0,0,0,0);
        }
mean = mean/(6*512*512);

}
```

When I run it, everything works fine until the value of "c" changes from 0 to 1. Then, the line accessing `img(0)(0,0,0,0)` makes the program crash with a segmentation fault error.

Also if I check:

```
img.load_cimg("image.cimg", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);  
img(0).print();
```

The result is:

```
CImg<float>: this = 0x14330f8, size = (0,0,0,0) [0 b], data = (float*)(nil) (non-shared) = [ ].
```

I am very sure about the correctness of the code, and the integrity of the image (I tried with different ones). Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: This piece of code looks fine. I guess something is wrong in function load_cimg

Comment: Do you really plan to load a image inside a loop inside a loop inside a loop? Seems slow (when it works).

Comment: It would be much more efficient to load the entire image once, then read through the pixels in memory...